# What are the missing header files here (C code)?

Tags: c, code-analysis

I'm reading a C tutorial, and it has something missing after `#include`:

```
/***  reads in n integers from a file,
      then prints the values to another file as type float  ***/
#include        /***  for file manipulation functions  ***/
#include       /***  for malloc()  ***/

main()
{
  int i, n, *x;
  char file_name[FILENAME_MAX];
  FILE *fp;

  printf("file name for input: "); scanf("%s", file_name);
  fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    {
      printf("error: could not open file %s\n", file_name);
      exit(-1);
    }

  fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
  x = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

What's missing?

Comment: #include malloc.h  // man malloc would have told you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> // for file manipulation
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc()
```

This is easily google-able.

Comment: Thank You Very Much, I'll memorize these libraries

Comment: @Adel.  These are NOT libraries.  They are headers.  You must understand the distinction.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - Thank You So Much , I've read about it and learned it now

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Couldn't you just search?

Comment: Looks like posting here got the answer just as fast. ☹